# Add history view to my model in Django

Tags: python, django, admin, history

When I make a change in my Django models, how can I add a history in the admin?, when i save in other template or shell

I'm using [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) 1.6 in the admin. The changes are stored, but in another template I don't see these changes. How can I fix this problem?

```
class Modelo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("nombre", "marca")
        verbose_name_plural = u'Modelos'
        verbose_name=u'Modelos'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) app

Some simple usage (from the docs, after you configured the app):

```
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> poll = Poll.objects.create(question="what's up?", pub_date=datetime.now())
>>>
>>> poll.history.all()
[<HistoricalPoll: Poll object as of 2010-10-25 18:03:29.855689>]
```